# Silverstripe4.0.3 file permissions after installation

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have installed SilverStripe 4.0.3 on a webserver and at the end of the installation this message is displayed:

**"After the install, the assets directory is the only directory that needs write access."**

When I try to search for information on what kind of file permissions I should set manually (if any), I can't find anything.

This is how the permissions look like after the installation:

```
 drwxrwxr-x  3 myuser myuser       4096 Feb 11 21:56 assets
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser       907 Feb 11 21:49 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser www-data     133925 Feb 11 21:49 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser       1406 Feb  5 05:15 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxr-x  1 myuser www-data     535 Feb 11 21:53 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser www-data     1221 Feb 11 21:49 install-frameworkmissing.html
drwxrwxr-x  4 myuser myuser       4096 Feb 11 21:49 mysite
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser       854 Feb  5 05:15 phpcs.xml.dist
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser       1804 Feb  5 05:15 README.md
drwxrwsr-x  3 myuser www-data     4096 Feb 11 21:49 resources
drwxrwsr-x  3 myuser www-data     4096 Feb 11 21:49 themes
drwxrwsr-x 25 myuser www-data     4096 Feb 11 21:49 vendor
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser www-data     585 Feb 11 21:49 web.config
```

For example, is the file permissions on the "resources" folder wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those permissions look fine. The installer tells you it needs those permissions just in case something went wrong when setting the permissions on the `assets` folder.

The message states it's the only directory that needs to be writable. It does not mean other folders shouldn't be writable.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Then I guess that I can set all files group to www-data and files permissions to 644 and directories 755 (except the assets folder).